# ¿Como iterar dos filas de una columna en un dataframe, y eliminar un resultado?

Tags: python, pandas

Cordial saludo,

Mi DataFrame consiste en una lista de nombres (B1) y su estado en el tiempo (B5), quiero realizar una verificación y que elimine si un estado se repite sin seguir la secuencia. La verificación se debe hacer por cada nombre de B1

| FECHA | B1 | B2 | B4 | B5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/03/2021 11:57 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 11:57 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:31 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:31 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:31 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | up |

---

Te comparto lo que llevo

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
print("Ingrese la ruta de los archivos .csv del mes correspondiente")
carpeta = input("")
os.chdir(carpeta)
extension = 'csv'
todos_los_archivos = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combinado_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in todos_los_archivos ])
combinado_csv.to_csv("SOE_Mes.csv", index=False)
print("Archivo Creado Satisfactoriamente")
df = pd.read_csv(carpeta+"\SOE_Mes.csv", sep = ';', low_memory=False)
df.sort_values(by = ["B3", "B1", "FECHA", "B5"])
```

Luego de organizar el DF, es necesario eliminar aquellos registros que tengan en la columna B5 un valor repetido (down - up), sin embargo, esto se debe realizar verificando que el valor de B1 sea igual, porque en B1 tengo n cantidad de nombres diferentes.

| FECHA | B1 | B2 | B4 | B5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/03/2021 11:57 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 11:57 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:45 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:45 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:45 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:46 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:47 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:48 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | down |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendidio bien,lo que quieres es filtrar el DF y dejar solamente las filas en las que la columna 'B5? cambia de 'up' a 'down' o de 'down' a 'up'.. Si es así, este código lo hace.

```
import pandas as pd

# Definir la tabla como un DataFrame de pandas
datos = {
    'FECHA': ['1/03/2021 11:57', '1/03/2021 11:57', '1/03/2021 13:44', '1/03/2021 13:44', '1/03/2021 16:31', '1/03/2021 16:31', '1/03/2021 13:44', '1/03/2021 16:31'],
    'B1': ['GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM3', 'GAM3'],
    'B2': ['GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT51', 'GBT51'],
    'B4': ['Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional'],
    'B5': ['down', 'up', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'up']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

# Filtrar las filas donde la columna 'B5' cambia de 'up' a 'down' o de 'down' a 'up'
df_filtrado = df[df['B5'].ne(df['B5'].shift())]

# Imprimir el DataFrame filtrado
df_filtrado
```

Con tus datos, creamos el DataFrame.

**df['B5']** Accedemos a la columna 'B5'

**df['B5'].shift()** La función shift() desplaza los valores de la columna 'B5' una posición hacia arriba. El resultado es una serie que contiene los valores de la columna 'B5' desplazados una fila hacia arriba.

**df['B5'].ne(df['B5'].shift())** La función ne() (not equal) compara elemento por elemento los valores de las dos series y devuelve una serie booleana que indica si cada elemento es diferente (True) o igual (False).

**df[df['B5'].ne(df['B5'].shift())]** Pasamos la serie booleana generada en el paso anterior como índice para el DataFrame df. Esto filtra el DataFrame original y devuelve solo las filas donde la serie booleana tiene el valor True, es decir, donde la columna 'B5' cambia de 'up' a 'down' o de 'down' a 'up'.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto lo que llevo

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
print("Ingrese la ruta de los archivos .csv del mes correspondiente")
carpeta = input("")
os.chdir(carpeta)
extension = 'csv'
todos_los_archivos = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combinado_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in todos_los_archivos ])
combinado_csv.to_csv("SOE_Mes.csv", index=False)
print("Archivo Creado Satisfactoriamente")
df = pd.read_csv(carpeta+"\SOE_Mes.csv", sep = ';', low_memory=False)
df.sort_values(by = ["B3", "B1", "FECHA", "B5"])
```

Luego de organizar el DF, es necesario eliminar aquellos registros que tengan en la columna B5 un valor repetido (down - up), sin embargo, esto se debe realizar verificando que el valor de B1 sea igual, porque en B1 tengo n cantidad de nombres diferentes.

| FECHA | B1 | B2 | B4 | B5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/03/2021 11:57 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 11:57 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 13:44 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:45 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:45 | GAM1 | GBT52 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:45 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | down |
| 1/03/2021 16:46 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:47 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | up |
| 1/03/2021 16:48 | GAM3 | GBT51 | Estado Operacional | down |

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso, quizás esta sea la solución. Primero agrupamos de acuerdo con el contenido de la columna 'B1' y a continuación realizamos el filtrado, de la misma manera que te he indicado en la respueta anterior.

Al aplicar las funciónes **groupby** y **apply**, el resultado final puede contener índices que no sean consecutivos y mantengan los índices originales de los grupos, por eso los reiniciamos con la función **reset_index**

```
import pandas as pd

# Definir la tabla como un DataFrame de pandas
datos = {
    'FECHA': ['1/03/2021 11:57', '1/03/2021 11:57', '1/03/2021 13:44', '1/03/2021 13:44', '1/03/2021 16:31', '1/03/2021 16:31', '1/03/2021 13:44', '1/03/2021 16:31'],
    'B1': ['GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM1', 'GAM3', 'GAM3'],
    'B2': ['GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT52', 'GBT51', 'GBT51'],
    'B4': ['Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional', 'Estado Operacional'],
    'B5': ['down', 'up', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'up']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

# Filtrar los cambios en la columna 'B5' dentro de cada grupo de la columna 'B1'
df_filtrado = df.groupby('B1').apply(lambda x: x[x['B5'].ne(x['B5'].shift())])

# Reiniciar los índices del DataFrame filtrado
df_filtrado = df_filtrado.reset_index(drop=True)

# Imprimir el DataFrame filtrado
df_filtrado
```